# How do I update a specific row in a specific column in SQlite in Java?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

So I have a pretty simple question I believe but can't seem to find any answers.

I am trying to update a single row of a single column in SQlite but using what I have right now, I seem to update the column for every row:

```
public void updateCompletedSessions(int i, User u) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(ScheduleDbHelper.COLUMN_COMPLETION, i);

        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

        database.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, "Username="+"Username", null);
    }
```

I have a User as argument to be able o check the name of that user so the Username column all have unique values of course, but where do I do the check? I'm thinking it has something to do with the last argument to the update() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition:

```
"Username="+"Username"
```

is equivalent to:

```
"Username=Username"
```

which is always TRUE and this is why you update all the rows of the table.
Your method's `updateCompletedSessions()` 2nd argument is `u` which is an object of type `User` and I assume there is a method defined for the class `User` like `getName()` or something similar.
If this is the case then use it like this:

```
database.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, "Username=?", new String[] {u.getName()});
```

Always use placeholders `?` and pass their values in the 4th argumement of `update()` instead of concatenating the arguments.

Comment: Thank you. Very clear and straightforward! It works.